# Get value in php double data type format

Tags: php, type-conversion

```
$td = 4.0;
echo $td;
```

The output is 4;
But I want real number (4.0) in double data type;

Comment: the loose typing of php makes this nonsense

Comment: @nogad for displaying purposes, 4 and 4.0 are different. But got PHP, it uses it almost identically.

Comment: yeah i think he's confusing that.

Comment: What is the status of this question? There are answers given yet you neither commented under them nor accepted an answer in order to mark it as solved.

Comment: As @FunkFortyNiner said, why didn't you accept any answers nor comment on them?

Answer (score 5):

First, not to be nitpicky, but PHP doesn't have the type you want*. When you do `$td = 4.0;` you have created a [float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

If you inspect it with `var_dump($td);`, you'll see: `float 4`. Since there isn't really a concept of significant figures here, the zero after the decimal is not relevant to the stored value.

Second, when you do `echo $td;`, PHP will output the string representation of  `float 4`. Again, without somehow specifying that you want to display *n* decimal places, PHP will omit any trailing zeroes. For another example, if you did this

```
$td = 4.00010000;
echo $td;
```

You'd see

> 4.0001

This is why the other answers/comments are guiding you toward a formatting solution. Because what you're really needing to do is not to change the type of the variable, because it's already stored in an appropriate type. You just need to specify how it should be displayed when it's converted to a string. There are different ways to do that. If you use [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), you can specify a number of decimal places to display. Here's how you make it show one, for example:

```
printf('%.1f', $td);
```

The `'%.1f'` is a format string. The `.1` part is what tells it to show one decimal place. But you aren't changing the type. It's just output formatting.

<sub>*[Here's a list of PHP's native types. And I was sort of mistaken, it does indicate that float is aka double.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`printf`](http://php.net/printf)

`echo printf("%f\n", $td);`

Comment: That gives me 4.000000 9, I would just use $td = '4.0';
echo $td;

Answer (score 0):

Check this out -> string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] ) 
Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$td = 4.0;
echo number_format($td,1);
```

this will spit out 4.0 the "1" is the number of decimals you want in the number

Comment: in which case $td doesn't need setting at 4.0 it could be $td=4

Comment: yes but that's not what he asked for, this will produce what he asked for.

Comment: $td = 4; echo number_format($td,1); gives the exact same result as $td = 4.0; echo number_format($td,1);, therefore what he asked for

Comment: lol ok, sounds good. I'll stick with my answer but thanks for the input.